# Is there a media manager which can look up / scrape TV show season and episode numbers?

Tags: video, collection-manager

I am looking to organize the TV shows that I have transferred from my Tivo (using [Pytivo](https://pytivo.sourceforge.io/wiki/index.php/PyTivo)) for viewing in [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/). Kodi expects that TV shows video files [have the season number and episode number in their path](https://kodi.wiki/view/Naming_video_files/TV_shows):

> `Season ## - Episode ##`
>
> "Season [season#] - Episode [episode#]" anywhere in the file name

I have created a small script to convert the Pytivo metadata `.txt` files to `.nfo` format for Kodi (and other media managers) but have hit a snag: The Tivo metadata **does not contain season and episode numbers**, all I have is the TV Show Series name and the Episode Name / Description. Example:

```
seriesTitle: NOVA
description: Planets are explored. Is there somewhere else in the solar system where life might flourish?
title: NOVA
showingBits: 12291
displayMajorNumber: 712
isEpisode: true
originalAirDate: 2019-07-24T00:00:00Z
programId: EP0000017787-0407556457
callsign: WUNEDT2
time: 2019-07-25T01:00:00Z
episodeTitle: Inner Worlds
vExecProducer: Apsell|Paula S.
```

A quick Google search reveals this particular example is [Season 46 Episode 12](https://www.thetvdb.com/series/nova/episodes/7167021)

I am looking for a media manager / organizer which can **scrape the actual season and episode numbers for me** because so far, every one I have found only scrapes metadata *about the episode which it extracted from the filename*.

I have already tried:

- Tiny Media Manager (Detected the TV shows but didn't see episodes at all)
- TV Rename (Couldn't make it work / read the NFO files)
- Jellyfin (didn't detect the shows at all)

Is there any media manager which can look up TV Show episode numbers for me, and rename the files?